# How to run a docker image from java Program?

Tags: java, shell, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I'm trying to run an Ubuntu image from a java program using a script; here is how:

my java code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    executeCommand("/home/abrahem/IdeaProjects/untitled3/src/createContainer.sh");
}


public static void executeCommand(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if (!file.isFile()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The file " + filePath + " does not exist");
    }
    try {
        if (isLinux()) {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh " + filePath);
            p.waitFor(); // i tried to remove this but still not work for my me 
        } else if (isWindows()) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " + filePath);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here is my **createContainer.sh** script file:

```sh
#!bin/sh
sudo docker run ubuntu
```

when I go to `bin` and type:

```sh
docker ps
```

or

```sh
docker ps -a
```

It should show the running Ubuntu container, but it doesn't.

Note: there is nothing wrong with the shell location; I try to create file in shell file and it works.

Comment: debug your code in try block.

Comment: ```sudo docker run --name myubuntu -itd ubuntu``` try this instead.

Comment: @RamPrakash thank for comment, but how? there is no exception to debug and i have try block.

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung i tried,but still not work for me

Comment: @RamPrakash how to pass password with command in case need password?

Comment: What is the output of `docker ps -a`  after you run your program? `docker run  ubuntu` will exit immediately as there is no entrypoint to run.

Comment: What is the output of docker ps -a after you run your program? nothing at all

Comment: Did you try to run your java program from admin user? Or did you try to expand execution permissions for your script/docker and don't use `sudo`?

Comment: You can try and follow this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/run-shell-command-in-java to obtain the output from the program you run.

Comment: What happens in this code if a directory name has a space in it?  Or a semicolon?  And as @ZhenyaM suggests, your program itself is running with root permissions?

Answer (score 1):

You do not capture any error messages or normal output from your process. Maybe it just works?

Use [getErrorStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream()) and getOutputStream() methods of Process to capture the output from the process somewhat like described [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-convert-inputstream-object-to-a-string-in-java). You may just see the expected output. If  not, it should be the error message on the error stream.